# setting image of slider

Tags: cocoa

How can i set  an image to a circular slider, which is an object of NSSlider. I have called setImage: method, but does not work out. What could be the alternative approach to do so.

Comment: Sliders don't generally have images. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ya that i know, but i need to create an object which has the functionality of NSSlider while displaying images instead of slider knob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to subclass NSSliderCell and override its drawing. See [Control and Cell Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html).

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I am sure it will make out my requirement.